# Django Set Session Variable

Tags: django, django-views, django-sessions

Hello awesome developers!

I got stack with session variables.
At the moment I have two functions. In the first one I am trying to set session var, it looks like that everything works fine, but in the second I am trying to access this var and I am getting None. Does any one have an idea why is it so?..

Views.py

```
@api_view(['POST']) 
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = requests.post(CORE_ADDRESS + 'login/', json=request.data)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        response = response.json()
        request.session["authentication_token"] = response.get('authentication_token')
        request.session["session_user_id"] = response.get('id')

        print('token -> ', request.session["authentication_token"])
        #token prints fine here

    return Response(response)



@api_view(['GET'])
def session_user(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print(request.session.get('authentication_token'))
        #and here it prints None
```

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'backend',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'corsheaders',
'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    #'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

By the way, these functions are called from Angular frontend.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your SESSION_ENGINE setting? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_ENGINE

Comment: well, it is an interesting question. I think it was default (I mean I didnt set it up), I have checked in the internet and I added this line: SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache", but it doesnt change anything. 

By the way, when I do $ ... migrate, console shows this : "Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions", so I think by default it has to save it to db...

Comment: @markwalker_, and any way, if settings were wrong, why would print work in the first function?..

Comment: If you print `request.session.keys()`, do you see all the session variables you are expecting? Does `request.session.get("session_user_id")` work?

Comment: @AdamStarrh nah, `dict_keys([])` and `request.session.get("session_user_id")` doesnt work either..

Comment: Sounds like you're using locmem or something & server restarts will clear the session. Change setting to `SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'` locally to use the db to store session variables. Then try to get the session keys out again. You should also consider using memcache, remotely & locally, then reverting to a cache session engine.